# Pass data from table row to a new table via buttonclick (currentID)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, dynamic-tables

Basically what i need to do is to pass the **currentID** from **order.OrderID** in my database to a new table and show 3 columns in the new table for the current order via **OrderDetails**, this is all part of Northwinds database.

I have created the 2 tables and code needed to process the information, the first table loads from start and works just fine, but what i cant get working is that when i click the button the table i have put as empty **("drawOrderDetails")** for now to show up and list the currently chossen ID. All this have to be done using Jquery, and Json and creating tables dynamically via Ajax so the server don't postback, im a little bit confused as im very new to javascript mainly i have a hard time figuring out what the problem is!

Here's my code for document.ready:

```
        $(function () {

        // Laddar Order Tabellen från start!
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var url = "GetOrders.ashx";
            drawOrders(url); 
        });

        // Skapar Order Details Tabellen!
        $('.btn').click (function () {
            alert(this.id);
            drawOrderDetails(url);
        });
    });
```

Here's my code for the first table:

```
        function drawOrders(url) {

        var data = {
            "dataType": "jsonp",
            "data": {
               "maxdelay": 3000,
               "dummy": 0,
            }
        };

        $.ajax(url, data).done(function (result) {

            var table = $("<table id='orders'>").addClass("orderTable");

            var tr = $("<tr>")
            .append($("<th>").html("Order ID"))
            .append($("<th>").html("Kund ID"))
            .append($("<th>").html("Order Datum")).appendTo(table);

            $("#orderData").append(table);

            // Startar loopen vid ID 10300 och fortsätter.
            for (var i = 52; i < result.length; i++) {

                var order = result[i];
                tr = $("<tr>")
                .append($("<button class='btn'>").html(order.OrderID))
                .append($("<td>").html(order.CustomerID))
                .append($("<td>").html(order.orderDate)).appendTo(table);

                tr = $("<tr>").attr("id", "order_" + order.OrderID);
            }

            //rita ut dom lite effektfullt!
            var tbl = tr.find("tr");
            var i = 0;
            tbl.each(function () {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    // $(this).fadeIn(i * 10, "swing");
                    $(this).fadeIn("normal"); // slow, normal eller fast.
                }
                else {
                    // $(this).slideDown((lis.length * 10) - (i * 10), "swing");
                    $(this).slideDown("normal");
                }
                i++;
            });
        });
    }
```

And here for the second table:

```
function drawOrderDetails(url) {

            var data = {
                "dataType": "jsonp",
                "data": {
                    "maxdelay": 3000,
                    "dummy": 0
                }
            };

            $.ajax(url, data).done(function (result) {

                var table = $("<table id='order_details'>").addClass("orderDetailsTable");

                var tr = $("<tr>")
                .append($("<th>").html("Order ID"))
                .append($("<th>").html("Enhets Pris"))
                .append($("<th>").html("Mängd")).appendTo(table);


                $("#orderDetailsData").empty().append(table);

                for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    var orderDetails = result[i];
                    tr = $("<tr>")
                    .append($("<td>").html(orderDetails.OrderID))
                    .append($("<td>").html(orderDetails.UnitPrice))
                    .append($("<td>").html(orderDetails.Quantity)).appendTo(table);

                    tr = $("<tr>").hide().attr("id", "order_details" + orderDetails.OrderID);
                }

                var tbl = tr.find("tr");
                var i = 0;
                tbl.each(function () {
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        // $(this).fadeIn(i * 10, "swing");
                        $(this).fadeIn("normal"); // slow, normal eller fast.
                    }
                    else {
                        // $(this).slideDown((lis.length * 10) - (i * 10), "swing");
                        $(this).slideDown("normal");
                    }
                    i++;
                });
            });
    }
```

Any answer would be helpfull thx! :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITYjZ.png : picture of the first loaded table, the different Id's in there is clickable buttons.

Comment: For starters, I don't see how the url would be accessible in the click event. Or it may be, sorry for confusion. Not a javascript expert. :)

Comment: Oh well its accesable via GetOrders.ashx, GetOrderDetails.ashx and 2 library classes that i have in my visual studio project :) !! The json callback function is set there! So that's why the url is present, as mentioned, the first table **drawOrders** that i call as onload works fine, but i can't pass the id i click on in the table to be shown on the other table **drawOrderDetails**